# MySQL: Is a subquery the right move?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several products each with several images.
I am trying to display 3 products with only 1 of their corresponding images.

With the code below i get 3 different products with only 1 image being successfully displayed.
If i take off the sub-query LIMIT 1 i get 3 of the same product just with different images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```sql
SELECT pro.id,
   pro.title AS product_title,
   pro.price,
   img.image,
   img.title AS image_title,
FROM products AS pro
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT product_id,image_library_id
   FROM images_products
   LIMIT 1) AS ips
  ON ips.product_id = pro.id
  LEFT JOIN image_library AS img
    ON img.id = ips.image_library_id
WHERE pro.status_id='1'
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question-title mentions a "correlated subquery", but this actually isn't a correlated subquery; it's a regular (uncorrelated) subquery that you're joining to. So that subquery is performed *first*, *before* the join, and only returns one record from `images_products` *at all*. You'd therefore get at *most* one working image. I believe that the query you want is this:

```
SELECT pro.id,
       pro.title AS product_title,
       pro.price,
       img.image,
       img.title AS image_title
  FROM products AS pro
  LEFT
  JOIN image_library AS img
    ON img.id =
        ( SELECT image_library_id
            FROM images_products AS ips
           WHERE ips.product_id = pro.id
           LIMIT 1
        )
 WHERE pro.status_id = '1'
 LIMIT 3
;
```

using a true correlated subquery. (Tested.)

Comment: Nice...I came-up with something very similar.  The only thing I'd do differently, would be to use an INNER JOIN (instead of a LEFT) just-in-case I ran across a product without any images.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: I was assuming that if the product doesn't have any images, then it should simply be displayed without the image.

Comment: It'll be fine either way as an image is mandatory when creating a product.  just looking through the code for any thing silly as it didnt work straight away. Thanks

Comment: I had to change pro.product_id to pro.id which then brought up  Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column ???

Comment: @Ribbo: I've made the change you describe, and I've tested it now . . . and I don't see any errors. I tried a few different permutations of products having multiple images, multiple products having the same image, etc. I'm using MySQL 5.1.53; what version are you using?

Comment: Excellent the change fixed it. I am also using 5.1.53. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ribbo: Well, that's odd. I guess you had a typo or something. Or MySQL was just in a bad mood. Anyway, you're welcome. :-)